# Angular - boolean doesn't work in template

Tags: angular, data-binding, boolean

I have a problem with data binding and passing data from parent to child component. There is this value 'active' which should be boolean and I would like to change a class of a button depending on that value. So there is this parent component which passes true/false to the child, than I can even print out this value properly (e.g. in

tags) but whenever it comes to a check like 'active == true' it always gives one answer, no matter what variable active is. Can someone help me? =)

Parent component .html:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="columns is-mobile is-centered is-multiline" >
    <div class="column is-half-mobile is-4-tablet" *ngFor = 'let name of names; let i = index' >
        <app-controler [ingredientName]='name' active="{{newNames[name]}}"></app-controler>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Parent component .ts:

```
export class ControlsComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients:Pizza
  names = ['tomatoes', 'onions', 'cheese', 'peppers', 'beans', 'corn']
  newNames = {}
  constructor(private foodService:FoodService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ingredients = this.foodService.getIngredients('pizza');
    for (let name of this.names){
      if (this.ingredients[name] == 0){
        this.newNames[name] = false
      } else {
        this.newNames[name] = true
      }
      
    }
}}
```

Child component .html:

```
<button class="button" [ngClass]='{"is-success": active===false }' (click)='ingredientOnClick(ingredientName)'>
    {{ingredientName}} {{active ? 'yes' : 'no'}}
</button>
```

this check {{active ? 'yes' : 'no'}} also shows wrong output

Child component .ts:

```
export class ControlerComponent {
  @Input() ingredientName:string
  @Input() active = false

}
```

Comment: Instead of passing value to child component like this active="{{newNames[name]}}", do [active]='newNames[name]' & check if it works.

Also try not using '==='

Comment: Yes, that was it. thanks. So what actually is the difference between [active]= and active=?

Comment: [ ] used for data binding from source to view.

Comment: You can accept the below answer so that no further answers required from StackOverflow community.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing value to child component like this active="{{newNames[name]}}", do [active]='newNames[name]